Error running wso2 docker image on Macbook Pro M3
I am using wso2-integration-studio 8.2.0 (MacOS Apple Silicon) which comes with builtin WSO2 MI 4.2.0. I am trying to build a docker image with a sample project, however getting issue when executing the image.
Below is the error when trying to run the image
pritish@172-117-001-070 ~ % export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64      
pritish@172-117-001-070 ~ % docker run -p 8290:8290 -t healthcheck:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[2024-04-02 18:09:33,336]  INFO {EventAdminConfigurationNotifier} - Logging configuration changed. (Event Admin service unavailable - no notification sent).
[2024-04-02 18:09:34,482] FATAL {CoreServerInitializer} - WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occured while loading the Axis configuration from /home/wso2carbon/wso2mi-4.0.0/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:66)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.internal.CoreServerInitializer.initializeCarbon(CoreServerInitializer.java:208)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.internal.CoreServerInitializer.initMIServer(CoreServerInitializer.java:125)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.synapse.transport.netty.sender.Axis2HttpTransportSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:718)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:125)
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:312)
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:179)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.synapse.transport.netty.sender.Axis2HttpTransportSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportSenders(AxisConfigBuilder.java

Please let me know if i need to configure or setup anything
Thanks
Pritish

How are you creating the Docker image?

I think somehow you have built a Docker image where the base image is MI 4.0.0 using Integration Studio 8.2.0. (This is seen from the axis2 version given in the error log axis2_1.6.1.wso2v63. Micro Integrator 4.2.0 uses a higher version). When you use the Docker Exporter project in Integration studio, it uses the configuration templates that are related to MI 4.2.0.
As a result, the base image contains MI 4.0.0, but the configuration that gets applied belongs to MI 4.2.0.
org.apache.synapse.transport.netty.sender.Axis2HttpTransportSender
The above class was introduced in MI 4.1.0 which is not available in MI 4.0.0.
To resolve the issue, can you set the base image to 4.2.0 when building the Docker image using Docker Exporter project and try again?
